# Segmentation fault reading file

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    char ch;
    if(is >> ch && ch != '(')
    {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    char ch2;
    double x;
    double y;

    is >> x >> ch >> y >> ch2;
    if(!is || ch != ';' || ch2 != ')')
    {
        cerr << "Error: Bad record!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y; 
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    return os << '(' << p.x 
    << ';' << p.y << ')' << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Point p;
    vector<Point> original_points;
    cout << "Please enter 3 points:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        cin >> p;
        original_points.push_back(p);
    }

    cout << "\nYou've entered:\n";

    for(Point x : original_points)
        cout << x;

    ofstream ost{"mydata"};
    for(Point x : original_points)
        ost << x;
    ost.close();

    vector<Point> processed_points;
    ifstream ist{"mydata"};
    while(ist >> p)
        processed_points.push_back(p);
    ist.close();

    cout << "original_points: ";
    for(Point x : original_points)
        cout << x;

    cout << "processed_points: ";
    for(Point x : original_points)
        cout << x;

    if(original_points.size() != processed_points.size())
        cout << "Oops! Seems like something went wrong!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

After debugging I've figured out that the error is caused by this line of code:

```
while(ist >> p)
```

This part of code is almost 100% copied from book:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    char ch;
    if(is >> ch && ch != '(')
    {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    char ch2;
    double x;
    double y;

    is >> x >> ch >> y >> ch2;
    if(!is || ch != ';' || ch2 != ')')
    {
        cerr << "Error: Bad record!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y; 
}
```

Google and stackoverflow says that this error is caused by accessing memory in wrong way. I was checking this code for an hour and I can't figure out what causes problem. I've started studying streams today and this is an exercise in 10th chapter of "Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition)".

P.S. Sorry for my english grammar, it's not my native language )

Comment: You need to step into your `>>` overload, and determine where the segfault occurs.

Comment: An hour is a very short period of time. Keep working at it. Come back in a few days.

Comment: Okay, I've just had pure console when I was writing this code. I'll follow the advice above and hopefully will post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not all branches of your code in function `operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)` lead  to returning final value so I suppose that you're forgot push returning value  `return is;` in the end of function

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    char ch;
    if(is >> ch && ch != '(')
    {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    char ch2;
    double x;
    double y;

    is >> x >> ch >> y >> ch2;
    if(!is || ch != ';' || ch2 != ')')
    {
        cerr << "Error: Bad record!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y; 
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Ya, I found out this really quickly when I tutned on C::B, compiler immediatelly warned me. But I encountered another problem. My error handler fails to recognize end of file or something like this, while I was debugging I've found out that after last value is red program enters >> function again and leads to error "Error: Bad record!\n", however all the values are correctly red and stored in vector. Firstable, I thought that when we reach EOF while(ist >> p) becomes false. Secondly, if(is >> ch && ch != '(') should not let program reach second if.